# R: passing values to eval in nested functions

Tags: r, eval

I want to pass some query to lower level function that uses 'eval'. Here's a simplified example:

```
f1 <- function(x, q) eval(substitute(q), envir=x)
f2 <- function(x, q) f1(x, q)
```

What's happening:

```
> x <- data.frame(a=1:5)
> f1(x, a<3)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> f2(x, a<3)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

While I would like f2 to produce the same output like f1. Argument 'q' is some general query that is going to be evaluated on 'x'. I keep the example simple and general but I want to extend it's behavior on more complicated functions and queries. The thing that matters to me is how to "pass" the query "q" so that eval knows what to do with it no matter how many levels of nested functions there were before.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Is the body of `f2` the only thing you are willing to modify?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean...? I can modify any of f1 or f2 functions, the only thing that matters is they both work the same with the same arguments where 'q' is some general query I want to evaluate on 'x'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
f1 <- function(x, q) eval(substitute(q), envir=x)
f2 <- function(x, q) eval(substitute(f1(x, q)))

y <- data.frame(a=1:5)
f1(y, a<3)
f2(y, a<3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined just `x`. You need:

```
> f2(x, x$a<3)
> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: It is a **simplified** example. In general I would like the functions to do much more complicated stuff, so I want to pass the query 'q' as-is to the lower level function and evaluate it, so it does work the same in f1 and f2 with using the same arguments.