# ggplot within a function within a function: passing arguments

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, nested, tidyverse

I am having difficulty figuring out how to pass an argument through a nested function call to ggplot. An example will help illustrate:

```
library('tidyverse')

dset <- tibble(
  xvar = 1:5,
  yvar = 6:10
)

plot_inner <- function(.outcome) {

  ggplot(dset, aes(x=xvar)) +
    geom_line(aes_(y=substitute(.outcome)))
}
```

Now I can call `plot_inner(.outcome=yvar)` and it will correctly plot a line chart of `yvar` against `xvar`. However, the issue arises when I want to nest `plot_inner()` inside another function:

```
plot_outer <- function(..outcome) {

  plot_inner(.outcome=..outcome)
}
```

The intention is to let me call `plot_outer()` and specify `..outcome` as a column of `dset` which then gets passed through to `.outcome` in `plot_inner()` which then gets plotted by `ggplot()`. But it doesn't work:

```
> plot_outer(..outcome=yvar)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object '..outcome' not found
```

I've tried various combinations of `parse()`, `eval()`, `substitute()`, and `deparse()`, but could not figure out how to make this kind of nested function call work.

I also tried an alternative approach:

```
plot_inner_2 <- function(.outcome) {

  .outcome <- enquo(.outcome)

  dset %>% rename(value = UQ(.outcome)) %>%

    ggplot(aes(xvar, value)) +
      geom_line()
}
```

With this approach I can call `plot_inner_2(.outcome=yvar)` and it correctly produces the line chart of `yvar` against `xvar`. However, again I run into an error when I try to nest this inside another function and then call the outer function:

```
plot_outer_2 <- function(..outcome) {

  plot_inner_2(.outcome=..outcome)
}

> plot_outer_2(..outcome=yvar)
 Error: `..outcome` contains unknown variables
```

Any help would be appreciated. I would prefer a solution along the lines of the first approach I tried, but if anyone has a solution along the lines of the second approach, or some other approach entirely, I would be happy to learn whatever works.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to avoid using strings or tildes when passing the variable to the function argument?

Comment: @aosmith I would say that needing to use strings or tildes is not ideal, but it could nonetheless be a very good second-best option; if you have a solution in mind that uses strings or tildes I would readily welcome it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26297977/2461552) might be useful.

Comment: @aosmith Thank you, following that post you linked to, inside of `plot_outer()` I wrapped `plot_inner()` in `eval(substitute())` and that seems to have worked. If you'd like to post that as an answer I will mark it as resolved, or if not then I will post it and mark it.

Comment: You should go ahead and put your solution as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the link in @aosmith's comment, wrapping `plot_inner()` inside of `eval(substitute())` within the `plot_outer()` function seems to be a solution.

```
plot_outer <- function(..outcome) {

  eval(substitute(plot_inner(.outcome=..outcome)))
}
```

Now the call to `plot_outer(..outcome=yvar)` works as intended, passing `yvar` through to `.outcome` in `inner_plot()` which is then passed to `ggplot()` and plotted against `xvar`.